# Getting no suitable driver found error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I try to run this code, I get a no suitable driver error. How would I fix this problem?

```
public class DBConnect {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://***.***.***.**:3306/*******";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";

        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.print("Connected");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println( e.getMessage( ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where the driver was loaded.  Make sure the MySQL connector JAR is in your CLASSPATH, the driver class is loaded and registered, and your connection URL syntax is correct.  That exception usually means a mismatch between driver class and URL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Include this line prior to creating the connection (and make sure the relevant JAR containing the MySQL driver is on your classpath).

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```